# Font-weight not being applied

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts

I am facing css font-weight issue. I have a site where I want to reduce the font-weight but it seems fixed even the lightest weight i.e. 100 looks like this.
[image]

but I want it to look like this
[image]
Font I am using is Merriweather-Sans

My css file 1 which contains the css related to the body and headings:

```
body {
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  line-height: line-height($font-size-base);
  color: $color-black;
}

h1 {
  font-size: $font-size-h1;
  line-height: line-height($font-size-h1);
  margin-bottom: $spacer;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: $color-slate;
}

h2 {
  font-size: $font-size-h2;
  line-height: line-height($font-size-h2);
  font-weight: $font-weight-light;
  color: $color-crimson;
  margin-bottom: $spacer;
  color: $color-slate;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

h3 {
  font-size: $font-size-h3;
  line-height: line-height($font-size-h3);
  font-weight: $font-weight-normal;
  margin-bottom: $spacer;
  color: $color-slate;
}

h4 {
  font-size: $font-size-h4;
  line-height: line-height($font-size-h4);
  margin-bottom: $spacer;
}

p {
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  line-height: line-height($font-size-base);
  margin-bottom: $spacer;
  color: $color-slate;
}
```

My css file 2 which contains the variables declared in css above:

```
/* === Typography === */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans');

$font-family-base: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;

$font-size-base: 1rem;
$font-size-h1: $font-size-base * 3;
$font-size-h2: $font-size-base * 2;
$font-size-h3: $font-size-base * 1.75;
$font-size-h4: $font-size-base * 1.25;
$font-size-lead: $font-size-base * 1.25;
$font-size-small: $font-size-base * 0.875;

$font-weight-light: 200;
$font-weight-normal: 400;
$font-weight-bold: 700;

/* === Line height === */

$line-height-list: 1.5rem;
```

Comment: Could you put a small working snippet into your question as I'm having difficulty reproducing your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: Do I understand well? Why are you using **two** CSS files?

Comment: this import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather+Sans' only contains font-weight 400, I think that's why

Comment: @Andara Is there any replacement for this font where we can use font-weight 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this import https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans only contains font-weight 400, I think that's why.

and this font only support font-weight 300-800 https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Merriweather+Sans?query=Merriweather

you could use font-weight 300-800 by importing like this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
```

Comment: Thankyou! But I have lighter font-weights as well. Like the body has font-weight 100. What should I do about that?

Comment: well like I said that font only support font-weight 300-800, you should find another font that support font-weight you need :)

Comment: Which font can be replaced for Merriweather Sans?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple weights of Merriweather, you're better off importing the variable font rather than six static weights:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather+Sans:wght@300..800&display=swap');
```

If you want to find fonts in Google Fonts that have a very light weight, try filtering with "thickness" set to a low value:

[image: font filter in Google Fonts]

https://fonts.google.com/?thickness=1